# Bootstrap label+input+text position

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with the position of my elements.
I would like to have the label on the top of each input & some text on the right(of the input).

```html
<link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">

                <div class="panel-heading">
                   <h4 class="text-center">TEXT</h4>
                </div>
            
                <div class="panel-body">

                <form>
                        
                    
                  <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="pull-left" style ="margin-left:20px;">
                          <label for="1">1</label>       
                          <input id="1" type="number" class="form-control" style="width:120;"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-left" style ="margin-left:10px;">
                          <label for="2">2</label>
                          <input id="2" type="number" class="form-control" style="width:120;"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-left" style ="margin-left:10px;">
                          <label for="3">3</label>
                          <input id="3"type="number" class="form-control" style="width:120;"/>
                        </div>
                   </div>

        <br>

                  <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="pull-left" style ="margin-left:20px;">
                          <label for="4">4</label>       
                          <input id="4" type="number" class="form-control" style="width:120;"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-left" style ="margin-left:10px;">
                          <label for="5">5</label>
                          <input id="5" type="number" class="form-control" style="width:120;"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-left" style ="margin-left:10px;">
                         <label for="6">6</label>
                         <input id="6" type="number" class="form-control" style="width:120;"/>
                        </div>
                   </div>

                </form>

                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when i add some text after each input that doesnt work.

I'm a beginner, so it's sure that i'm missing something. 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```html
<link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">

                <div class="panel-heading">
                   <h4 class="text-center">TEXT</h4>
                </div>
            
                <div class="panel-body">

                <form>
                        
                    
                  <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="pull-left" style ="margin-left:20px;">
                          <label for="1">1</label> </br>      
                          <input id="1" type="number" class="form-control" style="width:120;"/> sometext1
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-left" style ="margin-left:10px;">
                          <label for="2">2</label></br>   
                          <input id="2" type="number" class="form-control" style="width:120;"/> sometext2
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-left" style ="margin-left:10px;">
                          <label for="3">3</label></br>   
                          <input id="3"type="number" class="form-control" style="width:120;"/> sometext3
                        </div>
                   </div>

        <br>

                  <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="pull-left" style ="margin-left:20px;">
                          <label for="4">4</label>       
                          <input id="4" type="number" class="form-control" style="width:120;"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-left" style ="margin-left:10px;">
                          <label for="5">5</label>
                          <input id="5" type="number" class="form-control" style="width:120;"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-left" style ="margin-left:10px;">
                         <label for="6">6</label>
                         <input id="6" type="number" class="form-control" style="width:120;"/>
                        </div>
                   </div>

                </form>

                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jM5hN.jpg <=it's the result of your code & what im watching for

Comment: this is the result of my code when i run it from the 'run code snippet' on stackoverflow: https://www.flickr.com/gp/138578748@N08/RBxW43

Comment: If you want something specific other than what you specified then please update your description, You may not be seeing the result correctly because of some other code you  have on your test page besides the code provided here.I have no way to know what that is without you supplying it.

Answer (score 0):

This code solved my problem

```html
<link href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">

                <div class="panel-heading">
                   <h4 class="text-center">TEXT</h4>
                </div>
            
                <div class="panel-body">

                <form>
                        
                <div class="form-inline">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="1">1</label> </br>      
                          <input id="1" type="number" class="form-control" style="width:80;"/> abc
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="2">2</label></br>  
                          <input id="2" type="number" class="form-control" style="width:80;"/> abc
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="3">3</label></br>  
                          <input id="3"type="number" class="form-control" style="width:80;"/> abc
                        </div>
                </div>
                </form>

                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```